# Dynamic notification icon for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Google Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). The FCM send the notification icon as apps icon. I want to send dynamic icon from URL but it doesn't work. Is it possible to send dynamic notification icon?

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"App Title",  
    "body":"descriptions",
    "icon":"http://example.com/abc.png",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  },
  "data":{
    "state":"contact",  
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/all",
    "priority":"high"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. The icon you specify in the `icon` parameter needs to be an image assets already present in your APK.

> **icon** Sets the notification icon to `myicon` for drawable resource
>   `myicon`. If you don't send this key in the request, FCM displays the
>   launcher icon specified in your app manifest.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: I know that, but there is no way to send dynamic notification icon from URL?

Comment: you can always write your own logic using data-messages